# Apache Ignite 2.14 Binary and OpenSSL critical vulnerability Version 3.0.x

Tags: openssl, ignite

i plan to install Apache Ignite Version 2.14.0 Binary Release (latest) on a windows server. I prefer ODBC-Connection to my application. ODBC Driver uses OpenSSL, but Version 3.0.0 to 3.0.6 has critical vulnerability. It seems that Version 3.0.7 has fixed the problems. Is 2.14.0 Binary Release (especially ODBC) affected ? If yes, when is a new binary release available with OpenSSL 3.0.7 or higher.
I can't find any information at apache site.
Thank you for your help

Regards
Guido Clesius

I could not find the OpenSSL Version that Ignite binaries were built from, especially ODBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ODBC driver for Apache Ignite is not shipped with any specific version of OpenSSL, it uses the one it finds on your system. So you should just try using it with OpenSSL version that does not have this vulnerability.